# Dynamically Adding validation rule in cakePHP 2.*

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I am stuck in a problem of cake php. I wanted to add validation rule inside model for two from fields only if they are shown the front end. Basically they are hidden . on change of a select box they are shown and I want them to be required if they are visible. 
let me show you my code

```
 <?php 
    echo $this->JqueryValidation->input('website',array(
           'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Website',
            'div' => true,
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'id' => 'InputWebsite',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter your website'
        )); 
?> 
<?php 
    echo $this->JqueryValidation->input('phone',array(
           'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Phone',
            'div' => true,
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'id' => 'InputPhone',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter your contact Number'
        )); 
?>
```

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#InputPhone').parent('div').hide();
    $('#InputWebsite').parent('div').hide();


    $('#purpose').on('change', function(e) {
      var optionVal = $(this).val();
      if (optionVal == 'Schedule a call') {
        $('#InputPhone').parent('div').show();
        $('#InputWebsite').parent('div').show();
        $("#InputMessage").hide();
        $("#InputMessage").val('');
        $(".textarea").hide();
      } else {
        $('#InputPhone').parent('div').hide();
        $('#InputPhone').val('');
        $('#InputWebsite').parent('div').hide();
        $('#InputWebsite').val('');
        $("#InputMessage").show();
        $(".textarea").show();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

In `beforeValidate` function inside Model, check that the select-box value is the one that need to be for validating the other field. Then if it was that, you need to add validation rule to your `$validate` array (using `$this->validate += array(...new rule...);`).